# Control of user rights to change objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, user-permissions

Imagine that there is a user and he has a certain order that is issued for him.
The user decides to "release" it and pulls the REST API handle:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') || hasRole('ADMIN')")
@PatchMapping(path = "/setFree", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<OrderDTO> setFree(@RequestParam(name = "id") int id) {
    final var order = this.orderService.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new OrderNotFoundException(id));
    if (order.getStatus() == OrderStatus.FREE.getId())
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();

    final var free = this.orderService.setFree(order);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(this.modelMapper.map(free, OrderDTO.class));
}
```

An authorized user with the USER or ADMIN role has access to this handle.
Question! What in this case prevents a user with the USER role from releasing an order for some other user.
How can this be validated? So that the user can change the state of objects only those that are "allowed" to him or that are related to him?
Take the current user in the security context and check that his `"SpringSecurityHolder"#getId() == order#getUserId();` ? But this is too primitive. How can such validations be implemented correctly?

Comment: I am not sure this question can be answered in non-opinionated manner, since there is nothing wrong with `SpringSecurityHolder"#getId() == order#getUserId();`, it will do the intended job. Most tools recommend doing this kind of check with the db query - `findByIdAndUserId(id, userId)`, which is essentially the same, but will obfuscate the true reason, making it unclear if the resource does not exist or you don't have permission to view it (this is considered important from security perspective).

Comment: Too primitive? Define primitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe when you say this is too primitive , you meant solution is not well abstracted and elegant in design.

If that is the question, to make it more elegant you can follow this approach

1. Define a AutoriationService within project.
2. You can define method specific to validate authentication for this particular method ( getOrder). Method name could be - authenticationForToGetOrderAPI.
3. You can define your custom implemenation of this method. Custom implemeantion could be "SpringSecurityHolder"#getId() == order#getUserId()".
4. You can use Sprint Security annotation @PreAuthorize to attach this method on top of getOrder API call. The @PreAuthorize annotation checks the given expression before entering the method.

More details for @PreAuthorize , please check it here - found this link helpful for Spring Security Features - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security

Comment: yes. i meant solution abstracted and elegant in design.

Answer (score 2):

`@PreAuthorize` allows you to use SpEL to refer to the bean method that perform authorisation checking.So you can define a bean for such checking something like :

```java
@Service
public class AuthzService {


    public boolean isAllowFreeOrder(int orderId){
       
      //access the order and current user information for the authorisation check
      //return true if it is allow. otherwise , return false
    }  
}
```

In this method , you can the get the order from the repository and check its required state. To get the current user information , here are some code snippets which you may find useful :

```java
Authentication currentUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
User currentUser =  (User) currentUser.getPrincipal();


List<GrantedAuthority> userRoles =  = currentUser.getAuthorities()
boolean hasUserRole =  userRoles.stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).anyMatch(a->a.equals("ROLE_USER"));
boolean hasAdminRole =  userRoles.stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).anyMatch(a->a.equals("ROLE_ADMIN"));
```

which I assume you use the default spring security `User` object to represent the current authenticated user .

Finally configure `@PreAuthorize` to use this method for checking :

```java
@PreAuthorize("@authzService.isAllowFreeOrder(#id)")
@PatchMapping(path = "/setFree")
public ResponseEntity<OrderDTO> setFree(int id) {
   
}
```